# Percentage tables and cross-tabulations from non-numeric questionnaire answers read from CSV in R

Tags: r

I have read an CSV file from a questionnaire with many non-numeric, nominal values, e.g, country codes, computer skills (Expert, Intermediate, Beginner), … via read.csv

I want to have the percentages of each answer for each questions, i.e. , similar to a frequency table given by summary, sorted by occurrences from high to low. Later, I also want to do cross-tabulation, e.g., country with computer skills.

`summary(data)` gives me almost what I want, i.e. it gives me a frequency table of the answers, but the frequencies are

1. Not ordered by frequency but by variable
2. Are not percentages.

`prop.table` should give percentage tables, but it works only with numeric values.

Is there any easy way? Which function can I use?

Comment: Go read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/324364) question on how to produce a reproducible example, and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started.  It provides percentages of records in each of three categories for a single variable.

```
dat <- c("Expert", "Intermediate", "Beginner", "Expert", "Expert", "Beginner", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Intermediate", "Beginner", "Beginner", "Beginner")

numeric.dat <- as.numeric(factor(dat , levels = c("Beginner","Intermediate","Expert")))

zzz <- table(numeric.dat)

prop.table(zzz)
```